# Creating Outlook Email with unique Message-ID

Tags: c#, email, outlook, vsto

I have created an C# application that will send an email whenever a user inputs information. The same application can be used to send a reply to the original email. My problem is that Outlook is not grouping the emails but treating each as unique email. I have read that a Message-ID could be used as the reference to keep emails together. However I cannot locate examples on how to apply this into my code.

```
Outlook.Application olApp = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook._MailItem eMailItem = (Outlook._MailItem)(olApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem));

eMailItem.To = "username@domain.com";
eMailItem.Subject = pMailSubject;
eMailItem.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
eMailItem.HTMLBody = pMailBody;
```

Is there a way to set a unique Message-ID, so that whenever a new email is sent regarding a particular subject that Message-ID can be used to keep all the emails together within Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the original message in your inbox and then Reply() to it.

```
try
{
  Outlook.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
  Outlook._NameSpace ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
  ns.Logon(null, null, false, false);
  Outlook.MAPIFolder inboxFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

  // loop through the folder to find the email - match on subject
  for (int i=1; i <= inboxFolder.Items.Count; i++)
  {
    Outlook._MailItem item = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem)inboxFolder.Items[i];
    if (item.Subject == eMailItem.Subject)
    {
      // found original message, reply to it
      Outlook._MailItem reply = item.Reply();
      reply.HTMLBody = eMailItem.HTMLBody;
      reply.Send();
      break;
    }
  }
}
catch
{
}
```

Comment: There is no original email. What are you going to do then?